# facebook login in modal window

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to create a modal login window for Facebook for a site using the Facebook PHP SDK.

That currently works to click the link to the Facebook user is sent on the Facebook page, make login and then returns to a page that checks if the user is already logged into my site and then direct access to his home or if you You must first register.

Current process:
Facebook login link
Redirect page on Facebook to check user and password
Back on my page access control

I would like to avoid that is to get out of my site and then return and create a modal only to click on that link to Facebook I open the modal, put username and password and send him back to the control page.

Procedure wanted:
Facebook login link
Modal for user and password without redirect
Back on my page for access control

I used this simple javascript code test:

```
window.open ({uri_Facebook_page_login} , 
_blank ,toolbar = no, scrollbars = yes, resizable = yes,
top = 300, left = 500, width = 700, height = 600);
```

The problem is that he does the redirect on the new browser window (the modal page).

Comment: You can use the JS SDK to handle login - then you will get a _popup_ window inside which login is handled, without the redirect. (Doing the login in a “real” modal overlay on your page is not possible. It has to happen in an independent window, so that the user can check the address bar to see if they are actually logging in to Facebook, or if someone is trying to phish their FB credentials.)